# Какие значения менять для изменения ширины NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android

Не могу настроить размер drawer, баловался с настройками, меня значение dp, но на устройстве очень узко

Код:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/primary">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/nav_header_container"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
```

Какие значения менять для изменения ширины?

Comment: Не понятно что вам нужно. Кто такой drawer? Значение какой ширины вас интересует?

Comment: @AndrewGrow, под drawer я подразумеваю боковое меню в приложении "navigation drawer". Ширина это насколько далеко это меню будет раскрываться в приложении.

Comment: Указанная вами разметка это и есть разметка вашего NavigationDrawer? Здесь установлено значение match_parent - максимально по родителю.

Покажите разметку родителя, внутри которой подключается NavigationDrawer. Там должна быть ширина.

Comment: Никакого `DrawerLayot` в той разметке, что в вашем вопросе не видно, но вы можете [почитать это](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/drawerlayout.php) . Здесь ширину дровера задает ширина, указанная для `ListView` и этот пример работает.